# ValueError at /modifier_produit/1 ModelForm has no model class specified

Tags: python, html, django, view

this is my forms.py :

```
class stockupdateform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model:stock
    fields =['categorie', 'nom', 'quantite']
```

my views.py :

```
 def list_nom(request):
      title='liste des produits' 
      form =stockSearchForm(request.POST or None)
      queryset=stock.objects.all()
      context= {
     "title":title,
     "queryset":queryset,
     "form":form, 
     }
     if request.method == 'POST':
     queryset = stock.objects.filter(categorie=form['categorie'].value(),
        nom=form['nom'].value()) 
     context= {
     "title":title,
     "queryset":queryset,
     "form":form, 
       }
      return render(request, "list_nom.html",context)
```

my list_nom.html :

```
<table class='table'>
   <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>categorie</th>
    <th>produit</th> 
    <th>quantite</th>
     </tr>  
    </thead> 
   {% for instance in queryset %} 
     <tr>
    <td>{{forloop.counter}}</td>
   <td>{{instance.categorie}}</td>
   <td><a href="{% url 'modifier_produit' instance.id  %}">{{instance.nom}} </a> </td> 
    <td>{{instance.quantite}}</td>
   </tr> 
   {% endfor %} 
   </table>
```

I have this probleme what i can do :
ValueError at /modifier_produit/1   ModelForm has no model class specified.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set variables with `:`, but with `=`. Assuming that you have `stock` as a class in `models`, you have to change your `stockupdateform` to that:

```
class stockupdateform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = stock
        fields = ['categorie', 'nom', 'quantite']
```

PS Please share code with exactly the same indentations as your code. It's important to share it that way, because we may think your indentations are not correct (this code would fall 100% cause of it).